# I am trying to generate all posible IP's using for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def ip_miner():
    for x in range(1, 4):
        for y in range(1, 4):
            for j in range(1, 4):
                for k in range(1, 4):
                    ip = f'{x}.{y}.{j}.{k}'
                    sys.stdout = open("test1.txt", "w")
                    print(ip)
                    sys.stdout.close()

def main():
    ip_miner()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this program and I use print(ip) as an output, it prints all of the posible outputs, but when I try to save them into the file, it only does the last one.

I tried using, pyautogui, pyperclip, panda. Still doesn't work

Comment: `open("test1.txt", "w")` opens a file for writing. Opening a file for writing overwrites whatever is in it already. You want to do `open("test1.txt", "a")`

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file in normal write mode with `open('test1.txt', 'w')` will clear the file's content. What's happening in your example is that the file is cleared each time you open it before writing a new IP, leaving only the most recent IP in the file.

There are a couple other issues you may want to address

- Redefining `sys.stdout` is almost never required, and can seriously reduce the portability of your code, you definitely don't need it here
- IPv4 octets range from 0 through 255, not 1 through 4

To avoid that, just make sure you only open the file once. The most "Pythonic" way is to use the `with` operator like this:

```py
def save_all_ips(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        for a in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                for c in range(256):
                    for d in range(256):
                        file.write(f'{a}.{b}.{c}.{d}\n')

def main():
    save_all_ips('test1.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course, I'm not sure what your use case is for this excersize, but you may want to know that this file will be lengthy, about ***57 GiB*** by my estimate.

Comment: You can make this more concise by using `from itertools import product ... for a, b, c, d in product(range(256), repeat=4)`

Comment: My question was answered, the answer is in the comment